# Unable to build opencv-3.0 with opencv_contrib modules for python

Tags: python, opencv, cmake, sift

I used the following guide to install opencv-3.0 alpha without any problems - http://rodrigoberriel.com/2014/10/installing-opencv-3-0-0-on-ubuntu-14-04/

But when I add the options for opencv_contrib modules, the build fails with the error-

```
Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_xobjdetect.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lWRAP
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpython
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [lib/libopencv_xobjdetect.so.3.0.0] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/xobjdetect/CMakeFiles/opencv_xobjdetect.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

My aim is to get SIFT API in python. Is opencv-3.0 is the only option, or is there an older version that does that?

Comment: check out the link i provided in my updated answer if you're still experiencing this. It works for me.

Comment: Version 2.4.5 is working fine for me, so I don't want to change it, but I'll try it on a VM and comment here.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. The issue may be that you need to update your opencv source to the latest. I opened an issue on opencv_contrib and received the following answer:

"you need to update opencv repository to the latest version to build latest opencv_contrib with it, current opencv_contrib version is not compatible with 3.0.0-beta (which you are probably using). Or checkout opencv_contrib near 2014-11-10."

*UPDATE*: I asked the question on the opencv forum and got an answer by the repository maintainer: [broken python bindings](http://answers.opencv.org/question/58332/broken-python-bindings-on-opencv3/)

Comment: @goelakash the point is the syncing of opencv with contrib, not whether you're using alpha or beta. It appears that commit 5466e321b8c8f97536002a357e5b7ff49a5d2bf9
 is the one working correctly according to opencv_contrib contributors.